# snapshot system for physical machine with device-mapper overlay

Tags: boot, mount, backup, snapshot

I'm trying to create a snapshot system on my physical development machine comparable to virtual machine snapshots. I do lots of experimental stuff that I might have to revert afterwards, but I cannot virtualize my system for performance reasons.

Using a software like [TimeShift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) isn't an optimal solution, because it has to copy the whole snapshot back to its original location, which can be time-consuming. I would prefer a solution that writes all changes to a container and just delete the container afterwards.

For Windows, I created something similar with the [Native VHD Boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824872.aspx) feature by using differencing VHD images and just putting the right image in place before booting.

On linux, device-mapper snapshots (see dmsetup, I cannot post another link) look quite promising. My question is: How can I assemble the (maybe even nested) structure at boot time and boot the whole system from it?

Comment: VMs used to have a performance penalty, but for most usecases, this is no longer true. Have you verified that experimenting using `vagrant`, `docker` or just plain old VMs _really_ has a performance impact?

Comment: Plain VMs are what I'm currently using. The main problem is memory usage. Development tools like Eclipse etc. need a lot of it, but if I assign too much memory to the VM, the host OS slows down and this has an impact on the VM, too. I haven't tried docker with a desktop session so far. But even if I solved my initial problem this way, the device-mapper solution would still be quite an interesting experiment. :-)